# How can I make my entire flex widget have rounded corners?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, widget, rounded-corners

I am creating a Flex widget and would like to make the corners rounded.  In other words, I don't want some component inside the widget rounded, I want the actual widget to be rounded.

I have seen this done in many places so it cannot be too hard, but all of the solutions I find on the internet do not work.

People say to set the cornerRadius property and then set the borderStyle to "solid" and borderThickness to anything.  This is not working for me.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you post some code?

Comment: By not working I mean the corners are not getting rounded.  I have made some progress and I am going to post a screen shot and some code very soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating an AIR Application, you can set a custom chrome, and you're whole application will have the shape you want.

[Here](http://technoracle.blogspot.com/2007/07/making-custom-chrome-air-applications.html)'s a handy article.

Not sure what kind of widget you're talking about though.

Comment: I meant widget in the most common sense.  The small little flex/flash apps that get posted around the web and are stand alone apps.

Comment: If you want a swf in the browser to have rounded corners, that means you should not have an opaque background. I remember flex has a default background that is opaque. Set it's alpha to 0 and add you custom rounded corners background sprite. That should do it.

If you've set wmode transparent in html, I don't think you can get more transparent than that :)